# Is there an app: remind me when I get back here

Tags: navigation

The basics of what I'm after is very, very simple:  Push a button, it notes your location.  When you reach that point again it **tells** you.  I've looked around and I don't find anything that seems to meet this description.

Use case:  Yesterday on the way out I noted two pieces of trash.  I generally pick up trash on the trail but not with that far and hard to go (3000' climb, 9 miles, many snow patches.)  Of course I didn't see them on the way back down.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is called a **GPS/location alarm.**

The basic idea is that you set a point and the alarm goes off when you reach it. People use them on public transport to wake up before their stop.

In this specific case you would probably want to make a note of the coordinates and then set the alarm on the way back down. Of course most GPS already have this functionality using waypoints just without the alarm.

Comment: I've seen ones that you enter the coordinates, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.  The coordinates are **here**, tell me when I get back here (don't go off immediately as I'm sitting on the target) and do it with an alarm I will note even though the phone is in my pocket.

Comment: Some of these will default to the current location when setting the coordinates. That would do the trick but tends not to be specified so you'd have to try it. *Tasker*, a general purpose task automation app for android, does this, but the UI isn't what you're looking for as it simply does too much

Comment: @ChrisH Siri Shortcuts on Apple, as well. Same issue, though - it aint made for this. It certainly can do it, though.

Comment: Another term could be a geo-fence. You'd have to alert based on an area instead of a point anyway because a phone polling the GPS in the background isn't going to be giving you great accuracy most of the time anyway.